# Are CAL licenses necessary for this?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

I work in a company and I have been confronted with the following problem.

I have to mount a server with windows 2012 Server R2 in which Active Directory will be installed to control the logins of about 25 users. A part will also install a management program that about 10 people will use connecting from their computers with a client program.

The question I have is whether with the standard version I could do this or I would need to buy CALs for the 25 users that will use the Active Directory.

a greeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will need CALs per user / device if you use Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard as soon as your user / device connects to your server.

However, [Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2012/12/12/using-windows-server-2012-essentials-with-more-than-25-users/) includes 25 User CALs using up to 50 devices, so maybe this could be an option.

Some more info from a [blogpost on Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/volume-licensing/2014/03/10/licensing-how-to-when-do-i-need-a-client-access-license-cal/) and [this related serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/13956/active-directory-licensing?rq=1).